# Are longer days attributable to refraction or spacetime curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, refraction, atmospheric-science, event-horizon

There should be a perfect 12 hour day from sun rise to sun set at the equator, but there is actually about an extra 6 minutes. This is assumed to be due to refraction, but could it be spacetime curvature of light?

If the extra hours of the day are due to atmospheric refraction, then the sun should appear to be larger near the horizon due to a higher angle of incidence. But the sun is the same apparent size in the sky at any point during the day, whether at the horizon or at the peak.

This leads me to conclude that we are actually observing spacetime curvature of light at every sunrise and sunset, which would account for the longer days. Refraction cannot suffice as an explanation because the sun is the same apparent size on the horizon as it is at its peak.

Thoughts?

Comment: Calculate the magnitude of the spacetime curvature effect (as was done for light passing near the sun, to verify the predictions of general relativity theory in 1918) and see if it accounts for the correct size of the effect. (Hint, it is orders of magnitude too small to observe, given the "random" variations in the sun's apparent position from day to day caused by changes  in temperature gradients in the atmosphere, etc).

Comment: " _If the extra hours of the day are due to atmospheric refraction, then the sun should appear to be larger near the horizon due to a higher angle of incidence._ " How does sun have higher angle of incidence near horizon , and why would that make sun larger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sun were a point and there were no atmospheric refraction, the length of the day would be 12 hours as seen from the equator. (This is true for everyday of the year, not just at the equinox.) Another way to say this is the time between the "center of the sun rising" and "center of the sun setting" should be 12 hours long. The reason the day is approximately 6 minutes longer is because:

1. The sun is approximately 0.5° across. The time of sunrise is defined when the top limb of the sun first becomes visible, and sunset is when the top limb of the sun is last visible. Therefore, the sun is visible 0.25° before the center of the sun "rises".
2. Atmospheric refraction causes the sun to appear to be higher than if there were no atmosphere. At the horizon, the standard amount of refraction used in most calculations is 34 arcminutes (0.567 degrees) or more than twice the amount due to the sun's apparent size. Interestingly, the amount of refraction is highly variable. This study ([Variability in the Astronomical Refraction of the Rising and Setting Sun](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/378214?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)) found the refraction to range between 0.402 to 2.081 degrees!

Because the sun is far away compared to the diameter of the Earth, the horizontal parallax is not much of a factor. The average value is 0.00244 degrees (per the study referenced above). (Not to deviate too much from the question, but the horizontal parallax of the Moon is approximately 1 degree, and this has a large effect on the "length of day" versus "length of night" for the Moon.)

The deviation due to general relativity is very small to begin with. For the sun, the deviation is roughly 1.75 arcseconds (0.0005 degrees), per [Eddington experiment on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_experiment#Results_and_publication). The deviation as light passes the Earth will be much smaller due to the smaller mass of the Earth. Therefore, general relativity does not contribute to the times of sunrise/sunset.

Atmospheric refraction makes objects appear to be higher in the sky than reality. The effect is larger when the distance from the zenith (the point overhead) is larger. Therefore, the diameter of the sun in the vertical direction should be *smaller* than the 0.5° diameter because the bottom limb has larger refraction than the top of the limb; that is, the bottom limb moves upward more than the top limb and this reduces the diameter. Refraction does not change the apparent width of an object. This is why the sun (and Moon) often look "squished" in the vertical direction when rising/setting. (It is hard to find a good photograph that shows this for the sun due to the brightness, but many photos of the moonrise will show the effect.)

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for. I was actually about to start conducting the same experiment that you shared from Alberta. That just saved me literally weeks of time and thousands of dollars

Comment: one comment though.... If it is due to refraction, then wouldn't the sun appear larger near the horizon compared to the zenith due to a larger angle of incident through the spherical atmosphere?

Comment: Refraction only effects the height (the vertical dimension). If you had a line that stretched from the horizon to the zenith (90 degrees long), the top at the zenith would not be refracted, but the bottom at the horizon would be refracted upwards by approximately 0.5 degrees. So the line would appear to be 89.5 degrees long which is shorter than the actual length. The object looks smaller, not larger.

Answer (score -2):

You are barking up the wrong tree. The correct reason, which I read elsewhere, and nobody here apparently knows, is that the sun is bigger than the earth.  If the sun was exactly the same diameter as the earth, then however far away it was, then exactly half the earth could see at least a little bit of the sun.  Because the moon is smaller than the earth, less than half the earth can see a part of a full moon.

The sun's diameter is roughly 100 times the earth's, and the distance between the earth and the sun is roughly 230 times the sun's diameter, so do some geometry and you will find your extra 6 minutes.

Edit:

All the astronomy websites I could find today, also claim it is due in part to the “first and last bit of the sun”, which is the same nonsense that JohnHolz repeats.  On the equator, the time from sunrise to sunset, is always about 6 minutes LONGER than the time from sunset to sunrise.  But the time from moonrise to moonset, is always about 4 minutes SHORTER than the time from moonset to moonrise.  If what JohnHolz said was true, this discrepancy would not exist.  So for astronomers who do not understand basic geometry, that is the experimental evidence for the size and distance of the sun and moon being relevant.

Apparently refraction does add more to the time from rise to set for both the sun and moon, than I first thought.  Because the sun is not infinitely far away, without refraction, the middle of the sun would be visible for slightly less than 12 hours a day, but apparently refraction tips the balance such that it is actually visible for slightly more.  So  JohnHolz writes utter nonsense, votes down the question and my partly correct answer, then refuses to acknowledge his mistakes; but perhaps that is normal human behaviour?

Edit:

The true size is the reason, same size = always 12 hours, larger like sun = always more than 12 hours, smaller like moon always less than 12 hours.  Obviously the magnitude of the effect depends on the distance, even a 6 year old could see that.

Saying that it is due to the apparent size is wrong because the sun and the moon are the same apparent size.  I cannot understand how people can be so stupid as to believe such rubbish,

I wrote “the time from sunrise to sunset, is always about 6 minutes LONGER than the time from sunset to sunrise” it should have been 14 minutes (for Quito).  I also wrote “the time from moonrise to moonset, is always about 4 minutes SHORTER”, when actually it varies from around 1 minute to 5 minutes.  But nobody noticed because they haven't a clue what is going on, all they can do is repeat what they have read elsewhere.

I don't know what the figures on 'sunset times' websites really mean.  Because Quito is 2850 m above sea level, if the sun or moon rose and set behind the ocean, due to altitude alone day would exceed night by around 30 minutes.

Comment: -1. The date is not relevant when observing from the equator. Without refraction, all stars (point-size objects) are visible for exactly 12 hours per day regardless of date and declination of the star. If you were to use the center of the Sun to calculate the rise and set time, it too would be visible for 12 hours per day regardless of the date without refraction. -1. The true size of the Sun and Moon are not relevant. What is relevant is the distance and the parallax that occurs by being on the surface of the Earth instead of at the theoretical center of the Earth.

Comment: johnHolz you could be right about the date.  Stars are almost infinitely far away, that is why they are point sources.  But the sun and moon are not infinitely far.  Do you really believe that a street-light could illuminate half the earth?

Comment: My apology. I did miss one item from my comment. I meant to write this: "The true size of the Sun and Moon are not relevant. What is relevant is the apparent size (as seen from the Earth), the distance and the parallax that occurs by being on the surface of the Earth instead of at the theoretical center of the Earth." Of course, the true size goes into the apparent size based on the distance.

P.S. I did not downvote the original question. Please remove the statement "votes down the question" from your answer.

Comment: JohnHoltz, you are saying you understood the situation the whole time, and writing  “the true size of the sun and moon not relevant' was just a slip of the keyboard.  A complete and utter lie.